# ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:animated-vector-drawble:28.0.0

Tags: java, android, android-studio

[image: ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:animated-vector-drawble:28.0.0]

Как решить эту ошибку?
ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:animated-vector-drawble:28.0.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you've missed a character `a` in `drawble:28.0.0` part of the dependency.
Try this:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
```

Comment: Maksym, по-русски пожалуйста - мы на русскоязычной ветке Stackoverflow